# Matching Words from One Dataframe to Another

Tags: python, r, dataframe, match

I have two data frames -

One data frame has a column with a list of music artists (one artist per row). There are 10K rows. This data has demographics (Country, Age) for every artist.

| Artist. | Age | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Drake | 34 | CA |
| Snoop Dogg | 49 | US |

There is also another data frame with a column of artists and their songs. - 32,000 rows of this data

| Artist. | Song Name |
| --- | --- |
| [Snoop Dogg, Daz Dillinger] | Song name 1 |
| [Second] | Song name 2 |

I am not able to match the artist from the first dataframe to the second because in the second have Snoop Dogg and other artists with it. I have tried running a few codes using grepl, created a vector based on the first data frame column of artists to match to the Artist column in the second data frame but it runs "out of memory". I have also unnested the data but it gives me a big error saying the following:

Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector. x Subscript has the wrong type `data.frame< X : integer index : integer artist : character gender : character age : integer type : character country : character city_1 : character district_1: character city_2 : character district_2: character city_3 : character district_3: character >`. ℹ It must be numeric or character. Run `rlang::last_error()

The desired output is the following:

| Artist. | Song Name | Artist_Matched | Age | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Snoop Dogg, Daz Dillinger] | Song name 1 | Snoop Dogg | 49 | US |
| [Second] | Song name 2 |  |  |  |

A few codes I have tried -

df3 <- cbind(df3, yes = grepl(paste(art_v, collapse = "|"), df3$art))

Error in grepl(paste(art_v, collapse = "|"), df3$art) : invalid regular expression, reason 'Out of memory'

[image: Error Code]

Would really appreciate some help!

i haven't tried python for this yet. All my codes are in R, but if you have suggestion on how to do this in python, open to it for sure!

Comment: Don’t write `== True`, it’s meaningless code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could explode the column with the list using Pandas. And then merge the dataframes.

Something like:

```
pd.merge( df1.explode('Artist'), df0, on='Artist')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it's not recognizing the rows in python as a list. As a result, the explode() method doesn't seem to be working. It shows me a data type is an object. Do you know how I can convert it into a list?

Comment: I think I got it! just used apply(literal_eval). Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Then you probably did not convert the content to list but a string. So, it is better to provide some example code in stackoverflow questions that allows others to generate the objects in questions avoiding ambiguity. Also, please post you answer in case other have the same problem. cheers.